# Why does Terraform not provide if-statements

Tags: if-statement, terraform

Is there a deeper reason, why Terraform is not providing an if-statement to declare resources like this

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  if = var.create_foo  # this is not available

  name  = "foo"
  type  = "String"
  value = "bar"
}
```

To me this feels like a very common use-case.

I know that one can write

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  count = var.create_foo ? 1 : 0

  name  = "foo"
  type  = "String"
  value = "bar"
}
```

but this feels more like a workaround. This is also not the end of the story. In addition to this less readable `count`-construct, one also needs to refer to the first parameter everywhere else using `aws_ssm_parameter.foo[0]` everywhere.

So my question is: Why does Terraform not implement such a keyword? Is there a reason this does not fit into the design? Is it just technically complicated to implement and might come some time soon?

I am honestly thinking about writing some kind of terraform-pre-processor which would automatically replace all `if`-statements by the corresponding `count` statement as well as all references to this resource with an added `[0]` (or something slightly more robust). Any reasons that might not be a good idea?

Comment: There are other ways of doing conditional blocks and resources using lambda iterators, but they all lack the cleanliness of a simple conditional. On the other hand, conditional arguments are supported more easily with the new `null` type.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is simply not much interest in such a convenience feature at the moment. There is a [issue created for Terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21953), that is already quite old and barely voted for.